# Quicker way to implement numpy.isin followed by sum

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am performing data analysis using a python script and learned from profiling that more than 95 % of the computation time is taken by the line which performs the following operation `np.sum(C[np.isin(A, b)])`, where `A`, `C` are 2D NumPy arrays of equal dimension `m x n`, and `b` is a 1D array of variable length. I am wondering if not a dedicated NumPy function, is there a way to accelerate such computation?

Typical sizes of `A (int64)`, `C (float64)`: `10M x 100`

Typical size of `b (int64)`: `1000`

Comment: How large is a typical `b` and what do its elements look like?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul. I have now added the information in the post.

Comment: Are the values in `A` and `b` from a limited range or all over the place?

Comment: No, `A` and `b` are limited in range. Right now, they are ranging from 0 to 11,999. However, they may increase by 10x to 119,999 when I scale up the system in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your labels are from a small integer range you should get a sizeable speedup from using `np.bincount` (`pp`) below. Alternatively, you can speedup lookup by creating a mask (`p2`). This---as does your original code---allows for replacing `np.sum` with `math.fsum` which guarantees an exact within machine precision result (`p3`). Alternatively, we can pythranize it for another `40%` speedup (`p4`).

On my rig the numba soln (`mx`) is about as fast as `pp` but maybe I'm not doing it right.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from subsum import pflat

MAXIND = 120_000

def OP():
    return sum(C[np.isin(A, b)])

def pp():
    return np.bincount(A.reshape(-1), C.reshape(-1), MAXIND)[np.unique(b)].sum()
def p2():
    grid = np.zeros(MAXIND, bool)
    grid[b] = True
    return C[grid[A]].sum()
def p3():
    grid = np.zeros(MAXIND, bool)
    grid[b] = True
    return math.fsum(C[grid[A]])
def p4():
    return pflat(A.ravel(), C.ravel(), b, MAXIND)

import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def nb_ss(A,C,b):
    s=set(b)
    sum=0.
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            if A[i,j] in s:
                sum+=C[i,j]
    return sum

def mx():
    return nb_ss(A,C,b)

sh = 100_000, 100

A = np.random.randint(0, MAXIND, sh)
C = np.random.random(sh)
b = np.random.randint(0, MAXIND, 1000)

print(OP(), pp(), p2(), p3(), p4(), mx())

from timeit import timeit

print("OP", timeit(OP, number=4)*250)
print("pp", timeit(pp, number=10)*100)
print("p2", timeit(p2, number=10)*100)
print("p3", timeit(p3, number=10)*100)
print("p4", timeit(p4, number=10)*100)
print("mx", timeit(mx, number=10)*100)
```

The code for the pythran module:

[subsum.py]

```
import numpy as np

#pythran export pflat(int[:], float[:], int[:], int)

def pflat(A, C, b, MAXIND):
    grid = np.zeros(MAXIND, bool)
    grid[b] = True
    return C[grid[A]].sum()
```

Compilation is as simple as `pythran subsum.py`

Sample run:

```
41330.15849965791 41330.15849965748 41330.15849965747 41330.158499657475 41330.15849965791 41330.158499657446
OP 1963.3807722493657
pp 53.23419079941232
p2 21.8758742994396
p3 26.829131800332107
p4 12.988955597393215
mx 52.37018179905135
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Paul. Computation using `np.bincount` is almost 60 times faster over `np.isin` and `np.in1d` after reducing to one-dimension. Although both computations should result in an identical value, I see a slight difference in the final result. OP=1273046188243834.8 and pp=1273046188243834.5. I couldn't see any difference between the two implementations that could cause such difference. Any idea?

Comment: @Viswanath Yeah, it's most likely the order of summation. Your implementation sums the entire set of hits in one go, while mine sums each label first and then sums the subsums. But the difference is tiny, in your example it can only just be resolved at machine precision (try `np.nextafter(OP, 0)` and you will get `pp`).

Comment: Wow, you're right. That's only a difference of single floating point value. Thanks so much @Paul. On the other hand, if you had a chance to look at the other solutions to this post, do you have any comments on Numba implementation?

Comment: @Viswanath Nope, me numba noob. But I've added another solution (`p2`) which is another 2.5x faster on the example and still only three lines. And as a bonus if the small numeric differences bother you it can be combined with `math.fsum` for a guaranteed exact result (`p3`) at modest computational cost.

Comment: @Viswanath Not done yet ;-) If it still is not fast enough: You can use `pythran` on the `p2` code for another speedup (`p4`).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have changed int64 to int8 wherever required.

You can use Numba's parallel and It feature for faster Numpy computations and makes use of the cores.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def (A,B,c):
    return np.sum(C[np.isin(A, b)])
```

[Documentation for Numba Parallel](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#numba-parallel)

Comment: No, I'm still using int64 for the range. That's a nice idea though, will have lesser memory footprint. I've checked the documention for Numba and turns out `np.isin()` is not a universal function to be supported by Numba in `nopython` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `np.isin` is that slow, but you can implement your function quite a lot faster. 
The following Numba solution uses a set for fast lookup of values and is parallelized. The memory footprint is also smaller than in the Numpy implementation.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def nb_pp(A,C,b):
    s=set(b)
    sum=0.
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            if A[i,j] in s:
                sum+=C[i,j]
    return sum
```

**Timings**

The `pp` implementation and the first data sample is form Paul Panzers answer above.

```
MAXIND = 120_000
sh = 100_000, 100
A = np.random.randint(0, MAXIND, sh)
C = np.random.random(sh)
b = np.random.randint(0, MAXIND, 1000)

MAXIND = 120_000
%timeit res_1=np.sum(C[np.isin(A, b)])
1.5 s ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2=pp(A,C,b)
62.5 ms ± 624 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit res_3=nb_pp(A,C,b)
17.1 ms ± 141 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


MAXIND = 10_000_000
%timeit res_1=np.sum(C[np.isin(A, b)])
2.06 s ± 27.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2=pp(A,C,b)
206 ms ± 3.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_3=nb_pp(A,C,b)
17.6 ms ± 332 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

MAXIND = 100
%timeit res_1=np.sum(C[np.isin(A, b)])
1.01 s ± 20.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2=pp(A,C,b)
46.8 ms ± 538 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit res_3=nb_pp(A,C,b)
3.88 ms ± 84.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solution. Somehow, I could not get numba working with my code. I'm getting this error: [numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/179)

Comment: @Viswanath Does it run with the sampledata? This is a typical error if the inputs are of unsupported types (eg. lists with mixed dtype). Are all of them really numpy arrays or something different?

Comment: @max9111 I don't think `MAXIND` is the right parameter to vary beyond the values `12'000` and `120'000` given by OP. It should be the size of `b` and to a lesser extent `sh`, don't you think?

Comment: @max9111 I've added your soln to my timings but it is not as fast as expected on my machine. Anything obvious I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Paul Panzer You are measuring a mixture of compilation and runtime. On a second call of `print("mx", timeit(mx, number=10)*100)` you should get the runtime.

Comment: @max9111 but I'm calling `mx` once before (print statement above timeit import), that not enough? Anyway, if I call timeit a second time it does not get any faster. Does one have to configure numba in any way? (I'm running this on a fresh pip install.)

Comment: @Paul Panzer No not for this example. For transcendental functions, Intel SVML can provide some speedup. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html I measure 98ms for a single threaded and 17ms for the multithreaded version (factor 5.7 on a 6C/6T processor). Maybe you have less cores available?

Comment: @max9111 probably, when I set `parallel=False` I get `150ms` which is just below 3 times the `parallel=True` value. Well, thanks for the pointer and the explanations.